# Can't find raster

Tags: r

I want to display plots and draw shapes in geographic space for my research.
When I run a piece of code, I get an error message that raster does not exist.
I installed raster in response to the error message, but the result did not change.

```
# Install and call packages
install.packages("spdep", dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("sf")
install.packages("spatstat")
install.packages("tidyverse")

library(spdep)
library(sf)
library(spatstat)
library(tidyverse)
needs::prioritize(magrittr)

# Load data
# Load the administrative boundary data of Kanagawa prefecture and extract Yokohama city. In doing so, polygons with the same administrative code are merged.
ad <- sf::st_read('/Users/carlobroschi_imac/Documents/lectures/EGDS/05/egds_data4/N03-19_14_190101.shp')%>%>%
  dplyr::group_by(N03_007) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()
ad %>%
  filter(N03_007 %in% c(14101:14402)) -> y_ad

# Draw the administrative boundary of Yokohama city.
y_ad %>%
  st_geometry() %>%
  plot(border="white", col="gray")

# Spatial adjacency matrix
# Spatial adjacency by Delaunay triangulation network
y_ad_cen <- sf::st_centroid(y_ad)
y_ad_coord <- sf::st_coordinates(y_ad_cen)
y_ad.tri.nb <- spdep::tri2nb(y_ad_coord)

# Error message
Error in loadNamespace(j <- imp[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): 
   There is no package named 'raster'
```

iMac M1 2021, MacOS Monterey, R 4.1.2

Comment: I can't see `library(raster)` in your code, have you tried ?

Comment: Of course, there is a same message.

Comment: This is weird that if you loaded the raster library there should not be this kind of error. Have you tried to reload your R session, reinstalling properly each package and reload libraries ? If this doesn't work, it would be hard to tell you what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I installed via source files and it worked.

Comment: Standard install should works as expected. What you suggests is a workaround, but does nt give concrete explanation to the problem.